# How to switch between different views in a UITabbarViewController

Tags: ios

I tried to use the below code to do the switch:

```
 [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

I notice when I put this in  viewDidLoad ... nothing happened. But when I put in separate method, for example, when a button is clicked, it works.

any body know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?  To manually set the tab being displayed I just set the tab bar's `selectedIndex`.

Comment: yes, you are right, i use also select index, but I notice it doesn't work in viewDidLoad